# Solve_ivp() seems to run longer the 2nd/3rd/etc. time when I run the solver multiple times

Tags: python, solver

I am writing a program that is supposed to simulate the Social Force Model in python. Simply stated, this model takes some pedestrians models them as points in a 2D plane and they want to escape a room. They have some forces working on them, i.e. interaction force, driving force, etc. The program uses the solve_ivp() function to simulate the movement of the people. Now the problem started arising a couple days ago and I don't know what has changed. The solver usually takes between 5-10 seconds to complete, but on subsequent runs it sometimes seems to be stuck forever and once it ran for 158 seconds. I'm having a hard time debugging it because I'm not super familiar with the solve_ivp() function, so I don't exactly know what happens within it other than that it is a numerical differential equation solver that calculates the position and velocity for every time step.

Could it have something to do with PYTHONPATH?
In the image provided you can see that I have 2 paths defined, because I have 2 versions of this model saved. If I select one of them does that mean that python will only look at that folder when running the scripts?

Any help is appreciated!

I thought it might be remembering some variables that are interfering, but I run this piece of code to prevent this:
"""

## clean kernel

from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
get_ipython().run_line_magic("reset", "-f")
"""

Changing tha pathing also doesn't seem to do anything, although I am fairly new to this so I might be doing something silly.

The one thing that does work is manually restarting the kernel. However the problem reoccurs fairly randomly. For example I once restarted the kernel and had the solver work 4 times in a row but not the 5th, or once it worked 1 time before getting stuck. This randomness also makes it hard to understand where the problem arises.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problem with code you are writing, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [what you are asking] page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely that python path has anything to do with this.
You said it yourself - the problem occurs randomly every time you run the simulation.
Not very familiar with solve_ivp method, but after reading on it a bit I'd guess the problem is convergence. So something wrong with method parameters like step size (t_span). Try to play with those and see if it solves the problem

Comment: I didn't really fix the problem, but as long as the kernel is restarted before running it works as expected, which is fine for my current use case. In any case, thanks for the response.